# Отмена загрузки WebClient

Tags: c#

привет есть не большая проблема
вот метод для загрузки с URL картинки

```
public async Task DownloadFile(string adress, Image target)
{
    if (adress == string.Empty)
        return;
    using (var web = new WebClient())
    {
        await web.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(adress), "Data/" + adress.Substring(adress.LastIndexOf("/")));
        var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Data/" + adress.Substring(adress.LastIndexOf("/"));
        target.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
    }
}
```

Сделал `WebClient` локальным, потому что может быть несколько параллельныx загрузок и для каждой свой. Так вот  вопрос: как отменить загрузку не конкретном webcliente?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh159424(v=vs.110).aspx -- `Можно использовать CancelAsync для отмены асинхронных операций, которые не были завершены.`

Comment: да он есть но их может быть несолько как выцепить конкретную

Answer (score 2):

Стандарт для отмены операций в TAP -- это использование `CancellationToken`. При каждом вызове метода вам нужно передавать свой токен и тогда вы сможете управлять отменой по отдельности.

Однако поскольку `WebClient` был создан еще до TAP, то поддержку TAP в него добавляли пост-фактум и частично. Одним из ограничений является то, что он не умеет работать с `CancellationToken`. Но можно воспользоваться следующим трюком:

```
public async Task DownloadFile(string adress, Image target, CancellationToken token)
{
    if (adress == string.Empty)
        return;

    // регистрируем вызов CancelAsync() как реакцию на отмену токена,
    // using нужен для отмены регистрации после завершения скачивания
    using (var web = new WebClient())
    using (token.Register(web.CancelAsync))
    {
        await web.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(adress), "Data/" + adress.Substring(adress.LastIndexOf("/")));
    }

    // этот код уже не имеет отношения к WebClient, поэтому лучше вынести его из using
    var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Data/" + adress.Substring(adress.LastIndexOf("/"));
    target.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
}

...

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
await DownloadFile(..., ..., cts.Token);

// где-то в другом месте
cts.Cancel();
```